# How does IIS check for Dlls? - DLL Hell time

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a webapp which compiled successfully in visual studio, I see a bunch of output dll in the webapp's bin folder.  However, when I load a page through local IIS 10, I get the infamous cannot load dll error.

The IIS web app is just a web app which maps to my project folder directly, one that has the web.config file and the output bin folder.

[image]

The package looks like this in my VS solution:

[image]

I turned on the Fusion log and it shows:

[image]

Below is a more detail log of loading Azure.Data.AppConfiguration viewed in fuslogvw.exe

```
        *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (10/16/2023 @ 12:52:12 PM) ***
    
    The operation failed.
    Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.
    
    Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
    --- A detailed error log follows. 
    
    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = Azure.Data.AppConfiguration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
    (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/MyProject/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
    LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ce085641
    LOG: Cache Base = NULL
    LOG: AppName = f7dbdf88
    Calling assembly : (Unknown).
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\MyProject\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ce085641/f7dbdf88/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ce085641/f7dbdf88/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ce085641/f7dbdf88/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.EXE.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ce085641/f7dbdf88/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.EXE.
    LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Naturally I thought maybe my output bin folder of the web app does not contain some of this specific dll.  However, that is not the case, using the powershell command "LoadFrom" I can see I have pretty much all of the reference dll in that bin folder.

```
Write-Output ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\MyProgject\bin\Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.dll").FullName)
```

Why does IIS not see these in the bin folder?

I've tried the following:

- Clear out the nuget package cache. Clear out the package cache in
  Visual Studio and then run restore.
- Clean & rebuild my solution.
- Ensure my IIS app pool run NetworkService account and that the webapp
  folder and bin folder has access permission for this network service
  user.
- Delete out my  ASP.NET cache folder @
  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
  Files\
- Reinstall my IIS and setup the webapp and its app pool again from scratch in IIS.
- I made sure my web.config has binding redirect for these Dlls.

[image]

I could get pass the current error by register the dll with the global assembly (gacutil.exe) or manually copy this dll to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv but then the next missing dll would show up... I can't immagine this is the proper way to fix this.

Any hints or tips of what I can do next, I feel like I'm hitting a wall with this issue.
Why would IIS only see Dlls that are in the Global assembly cache and its C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv but not the bin folder or the user's nuget package at C:\Users\username.nuget\packages

Comment: bin folder?  It doesn't look there, make sure it is stored in the c:\myproject folder.  Or use the probing element in the config file.

Comment: Can you access the build folder of your project ? Can you see your dll there ?

Comment: "The IIS web app is just a web app which maps to my project folder directly, one that has the web.config file and the output bin folder." So did you create this IIS application manually? Or did you change VS project setting and switch from IIS Express to IIS?

Comment: @LexLi I did it manually through PS script: New-WebAppPool -name "MyAppPool" -force
$appPool = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool\
$appPool.processModel.identityType = "NetworkService"
$appPool | Set-Item

New-WebSite -name "MyWebApp" -PhysicalPath "C:\MyProgject"  
-Port 567 -ApplicationPool "MyAppPool" -Force

Comment: @BasilKosovan When in IIS, I can see the bin folder my site and when I select that folder and select "Content View" I can see the Dlls on the right pane.

Comment: @HansPassant You reminded me that I actually tried that step....however just to be sure, I tried it again, puting <probing privatePath="bin"/> within <assemblyBinding> of my web.config file....I then restart IIS via iisreset....upon loading the page the issue still persists.

Comment: @HansPassant  the weird thing is Fusion log  now shows that it was able to see that dll and yet I'm still getting the same loading error - LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\MyProject\web.config
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\MyProject\bin\Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.dll

Comment: 1)what is your application pool identity.2)set the iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the iis published root folder.3)Ensure there's no mismatch between the build architecture of your application and the App Pool settings. For instance, if you're building for x64, make sure the App Pool's "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is set to `False`.4)try to create sample new project with the dll which you are facing and see you are able to reproduce the issue or not